# Is there an un-edited version of The Lion King available on DVD/Blu-Ray?

Tags: alternate-version, the-lion-king

This is a very technical question, and I apologize for the barrier of entry, but it's for my sister who loves The Lion King

Are there any official DVD/Blu-Ray releases without the retroactive edits that Disney insists on? Looking for a version with the original SFX dust, the originally-drawn Rafiki holding Baby Simba, originally drawn Crocodiles, clouds still intact, original waterfalls, and no Morning Report.. all of that

Comment: TIL that George Lucas is in charge of the the Lion King franchise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No".  When Disney re-cut the film for IMAX release in 2002, they officially scrubbed themselves of the original theatrical (and VHS) version.  All DVD releases were based off the IMAX release.  Although several DVD releases have claimed to be "Original Theatrical Releases", they all have been based off the 2002 IMAX release.